# Expose a file in the macOS Finder from a Java console app

Tags: java, macos, file, finder

Using Java 10 on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS) Sierra or High Sierra, using Oracle JDK or [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) or [Zulu/Zing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) JVM, is there a way a console Java app can make [*Finder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finder_(software)) come to the foreground and expose the location of a particular existing file?

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a comment along with your vote.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly simply (more so then trying to do it in Windows, that's for sure).

So, after some initial research, I stumbled across [Shell tricks: the OS X open command](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/08/06/shell-tricks-the-os-x-open-command/), this is important, because almost all the solutions suggest using `open -a Finder {file\folder}`, which doesn't quite do what I wanted (it would open the file in Finder's editor (I was using a text file for testing))

Instead, it's suggested to use `open -R {file/folder}`

The next task was trying to figure out if you could call `open` from Java, I had thought that I'd have to execute it via a shell first, but that turned out not to be required.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command[] = new String[]{"open", "-R", {your file or folder}};
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
               pb.inhertIO();
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println(exitCode);
    }

}
```

I tested this on both files and folders

I also tested `Desktop.getDesktop().browse` but didn't have quite the same results as the above (more like `open -a Finder {file/folder}`)

Comment: I was asking to simply show the file in the Finder, not consume its contents. I want the user to see the Finder come to the front, a Finder window opened, and the specified file visible (preferably, selected).

Comment: And did you try it?

Comment: Yes, no effect. But I was running with the IntelliJ IDE, so perhaps that impedes the effect.

Comment: @BasilBourque Works fine for me. Did you try running the command from the command line? I'm using High Sierra (10.13.4) and Oracle's Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11) - but I can't see the Java version been an issue

Comment: @BasilBourque Also beware of the exit value, in my testing `1` means the file/folder doesn't exist

Comment: StreamGobbler isn’t necessary if you use [ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29).

Comment: @VGR I was testing to see if there was any output